# Efficiently scale df columns to zero

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to develop a process that automatically scales each `Series` in a `pandas` `df` to zero. For instance, if we use the df below:

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'A' : [0,1,2,3],        
    'B' : [6,7,8,9],            
    'C' : [10,11,12,13], 
    'D' : [-4,-5,-4,-3],
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I'm manually adjusting each Column so it begins at zero. You'll notice the increments are either +1 or -1 but the starting integers vary.

```
df['B'] = df['B'] - 6
df['C'] = df['C'] - 10
df['D'] = df['D'] + 4
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  0  0  0  0
1  1  1  1 -1
2  2  2  2 -2
3  3  3  3 -3
```

This isn't very efficient as I have to go through each series to determine the scaling factor. Is there a more efficient way to determine this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subtract first row by[`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html):

```
df = df.sub(df.iloc[0])
#same as
#df = df - df.iloc[0]
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  0  0  0  0
1  1  1  1 -1
2  2  2  2  0
3  3  3  3  1
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.iloc[0])
A     0
B     6
C    10
D    -4
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Cant believe it was that easy. Thanks @jezrael